# Replace a fragment with other fragment is giving error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Following is my code it is giving error in replace fragment part it is saying the found argument is android.support.v4.app.fragment where as android.app.fragment is required tell me what is error in my code as i am new to this so cant get the issue done

```
package com.example.xainshah.fragmentexample;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import layout.Fragment1;
import layout.Fragment2;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void ChangeFragment(View view){

        Fragment fragment;
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.button)){
            fragment= new Fragment1();
            FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place,fragment); \\ Error is here 2nd argument is not compatible that's what the error says 
        }

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.button)){
        fragment= new Fragment2();
            FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place,fragment); \\ Error is here 2nd argument is not compatible that's what the error says 
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use support fragment manager

```
FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
```

instead of

```
FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
```

Also remove import statement for fragment manager with support fragment manager too.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to use "getSupportManager" as stated by @passiondroid, you are using

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

where you should use support libraries for that :

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```